# react-native-maps:processReleaseResources task gradlew build failed

Tags: react-native

I check already all similar answers from Stack and also I lookup on [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues) but without any luck.

Problem occur when I install react-native-maps plugin, during a build I receive gradlew exception

```
:react-native-maps:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-maps:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Google Maps API is correctly added into AndroidManifest file. 
One additional remark I see also many warnings like

```
...\node_modules\react-native-maps\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.8.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.xml:14:29-81 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal').
```

However in build.gradle I add dependencies for

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
```

Any ideas how to resolve a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. 
An issue is a to long file path and npm not properly install react-native-maps module (there wasn't all required resource files).

During "compilation"

```
react-native run-android
```

gradlew task fails du to missing resources in maps module

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error recently and should have paid more attention to the error message. Message clearly states it out. `Failure to execute aapt`

#### Short Answer:

Make aapt executable

#### Slightly Longer Answer:

1) Run `cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace`. The output will show the build-tool version where you will locate the right aapt to make executable and the path to it. e.g  `Cannot run program "/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/aapt" (in directory "/home/user/testproject/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android"): error=13, Permission denied`

2) Right click on file 'aapt', click on permissions, click the checkbox marked 'Execute'

3) Run `./gradlew clean &&  ./gradlew assembleDebug` again and you should be good to go!!!

Comment: for some reason that particular aapt version was not marked as executable... solved it

Comment: `./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace` not `assembleDebeg`

Comment: excellent answer.  in my case, there were some 32-bit binaries in `builds-tools/23.0.1` which wouldnt' run on my system (Ubuntu 64-bit).  I had to install 32-bit compatibility libs to run the binaries (`apt-get install libc6-i386`).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue with this error response:

```
:react-native-maps:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-maps:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

The way I was able to resolve this error was by going into folder `node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android` and editing the `build.gradle` file with the corresponding `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `minSdkVersion`, and `targetSdkVersion` from my `{root}/android/app` level `build.gradle` versions.

This fix worked in various other newly installed packages which caused an error upon attempting to `react-native run-android`. Hope this helps!